# pthread_create not found in ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cocos2d-iphone, installation

I am trying to run cocos2d-x on Ubuntu. It shows this error:

```
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so  
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)
```

What does this mean?

Comment: it seems like it eventually finds `pthread_create` but it is missing `Doxygen`. Have you tried `sudo apt-get install doxygen`?

Comment: You see: `Found Threads: TRUE`. That means he actually found `pthreads` but ad oxygen is missing.

Comment: FYI, `doxygen` is a documentation-generator for CPP. I think it's ridiculous to make installation fatally error if it can't find a dep like that, but whatever. installing it should fix this.

Comment: @cat i am accepting it now. i also think now thats the only error until now. for some reasons i cant try installing doxygen right now. can i ask for help here itself if problem persists later?

Comment: @kshitijsingh If the issue persists, you can either [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34340650/edit) your answer or ask a new question -- up to you, a moderator may prefer one over the other however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it seems like it eventually finds pthread_create but it is missing Doxygen. Run `sudo apt-get install doxygen`, and retry it.

Comment: does not help ... here we are 5 years later and Ubuntu 20.04 still gets same OP message and I already have doxygen installed

Answer (score 3):

`pthread_create` may be present in few different places. Script checked them all and found this function in `pthread`. Then it looked for Doxygen and was not able to find it. Install it and try again, script should be able to proceed.